# From the Domain Service is there any way to get the current URL?

Tags: silverlight, url, domainservices

In silverlight 4.0 From the Domain Service is there any way to get the current URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does HttpContext.Current.Request.Url work for you? There's other interesting stuff in the Request object too.

Comment: no it does not should i be able to access that from within a domain service?

Comment: @Rico, I think so, I do. I'm using a LinqToSqlDomainService and I do have a "using" System.Web. Maybe you need to add a using/imports or fully qualify it - System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url ? What type of DomainService are you using?